How to Get GUID of Parameters from a Revit Model
We are creating a Custom Properties Tab for the Model Viewer, to display Specific Properties from Revit Model. How to get the GUID of Parameters of the Revit Models I am uploading to my project, so I can get the value of the Revit Paramter based on GUID and Filter the data based on the Selection using the ID's.

Does this help? https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/get-dbid-externalid
